# Read multiple values from a column in a csv file and pass to a function

Tags: powershell

I have a file named `group.csv` which contains data like the below:

```
Name  group                      location
A     group1                      local
B     group1,group2               local2
c     group1,group2,group3        local3
```

I am not able to read `group1`, `group2` or `group3` independently and I am therefore unable to pass the values correctly in to a function.

Here is my code:

```
$fpath = Import-Csv C:\klc\group.csv
foreach($abc in $fpath){
$Name = $abc.Name
$group = $abc.group
$location = $abc.location

 function display ($Name,$group,$location)
 {

  $group01 = $group

   for($i=0;$i -lt $group01.count;$i++)
    {
   try{
 Add-group -Name $Name -Group $group01[i] -Location Location -ErrorAction 
stop
  }catch [Expression]
  {
   Write-Host "Unable to Add"
  }
  Write-Host "successfully Added"
  }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:
1.  You probably want to move the display function above the other code so you can call it.
2.  You need to split the group value (read from the csv) to get to the individual values.
The line that says:

```
$group01 = $group
```

Could be

```
$group01 = $group.Split(',')
```